# Predict to raster multinomial gbm

Tags: r, multinomial, r-raster, gbm

Currently, it looks as through it is not possible to predict out to a rasterbrick a multinomial `gbm` model. See however that there is an easy way around this for relatively small raster grids - which is explained below. But the process here is very slow and not without its challenges when you a dealing with large rasters, many classes (in my case vegetation communities) and predictor variables. I am hoping the information below might be of use to anyone who comes up against the same challenges.

Below I try to predict the probability of occurrence for 36 vegetation communities using a multinomial gbm model and 20 predictor variables. My study area is a 30x30m raster grid with 213,000,000 pixels - however the code below relates to a small grid of 1221 cells that I used to develop/test the process.

```
> require (gbm)
> require (raster)
> require (rgdal)

> load("gbmmodel_p20.Rda") 

> print(gbmmodel)

gbm(formula = as.formula(Nclustal_1 ~ tcd_coast_disa_f + tce_raddq_f + 
tce_radwq_f + tct_temp_minwin_f + tct_tempdq_f + tcw_clim_etaaann_f + 
tcw_precipseas_f + tcw_precipwq_f + tcw_rain1mm_f + tdd_strmdstge6_i + 
tlf_logre10_f + tlf_rough0500_f + trs_land_pfc_2008 + trs88_sspr_g_50p + 
trs88_ssum_b_50p + trs88_ssum_d_50p + tsp_bd200_f + tsp_cly200a_f + 
tsp_ph200_f + tsp_tn060a_f), distribution = "multinomial", 
data = gbmdata, n.trees = 2500, interaction.depth = 2, n.minobsinnode = 3, 
shrinkage = 0.003, bag.fraction = 0.75, train.fraction = 1, 
cv.folds = 8, keep.data = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, class.stratify.cv = TRUE, 
n.cores = 8)

A gradient boosted model with multinomial loss function.2500 iterations were performed.
The best cross-validation iteration was 2500.
There were 20 predictors of which 20 had non-zero influence.
```

I stacked the predictor variables into a raster stack as follows:

```
> img.files <- list.files("/mnt/scratch/mcilwea/R/TSG/inmodel20_test",
pattern='\\.img$', full.names=TRUE)
> rasStack <- stack(img.files)
> NAvalue(rasStack) <- -9999
> projection(rasStack)
"+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-16.237,3.51,9.939,1.4157e-006,2.1477e-006,1.3429e-006,1.91e-007 +no_defs"
```

Its important to check that the names in the rasStack are identical to those in model above

```
> names(rasStack)
 [1] "tcd_coast_disa_f"   "tce_raddq_f"        "tce_radwq_f"
 [4] "tct_tempdq_f"       "tct_temp_minwin_f"  "tcw_clim_etaaann_f"
 [7] "tcw_precipseas_f"   "tcw_precipwq_f"     "tcw_rain1mm_f"
[10] "tdd_strmdstge6_i"   "tlf_logre10_f"      "tlf_rough0500_f"
[13] "trs88_sspr_g_50p"   "trs88_ssum_b_50p"   "trs88_ssum_d_50p"
[16] "trs_land_pfc_2008"  "tsp_bd200_f"        "tsp_cly200a_f"
[19] "tsp_ph200_f"        "tsp_tn060a_f"
```

Before running predict.gbm I call up the best iteration model

```
> best.iter <- gbm.perf(gbmmodel, method = "cv", plot.it = TRUE)
```

I can create a set of raster output images for my test area which has 1221 cells by converting the grid cells to a set of spatial points (as shown below).

```
points<-raster(img.files[1]) 
points.df <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(points)) 
coordinates(points.df) <- ~x+y 
plot(points.df)
coords <- coordinates(points.df)
rasterOut <- extract(rasStack, coords)
outTable<- as.data.frame(cbind(coords, rasterOut))
outTable[1:1,1:22]

         x        y tcd_coast_disa_f tce_raddq_f tce_radwq_f tct_temp_minwin_f tct_tempdq_f
149.1269 -35.6457         1.052329    10.82778    23.63533        -0.9852222     5.928154
  tcw_clim_etaaann_f tcw_precipseas_f tcw_precipwq_f tcw_rain1mm_f tdd_strmdstge6_i tlf_logre10_f
600         13.93321       179.9841       80.2064              491      1.945529
  tlf_rough0500_f trs_land_pfc_2008 trs88_sspr_g_50p trs88_ssum_b_50p trs88_ssum_d_50p tsp_bd200_f
15.6701                 0             0.38       0.09000003             0.55    1.590021
  tsp_cly200a_f tsp_ph200_f tsp_tn060a_f
33.33834    5.648166   0.03193555
```

To run the predict.gbm model

```
predtable <- as.data.frame(predict.gbm(gbmmodel, outTable, n.trees=best.iter, type="response"))
predout <- cbind(coords,predtable)
predout[1:1,1:38]

             x        y    e24.2500     e26.2500    e59.2500 g152.2500    g157.2500     g94.2500   m31.2500
    149.1269 -35.6457 0.001286283 0.0006473167 0.002043077 0.4973372 8.686316e-05 0.0006710651 0.01067058
         m36.2500    m68.2500    MU11.2500    MU45.2500 OTHER.2500  p14.2500     p15.2500     p17.2500
    0.004314056 0.007128109 0.0005012718 0.0006254022  0.1727706 0.1411112 0.0009099294 0.0002520156
         p19.2500    p20.2500     p22.2500   p220.2500    p23.2500   p24.2500    p27.2500   p338.2500
    0.003205936 0.002534798 0.0001474091 0.001214219 0.008455798 0.01701965 0.001879607 0.002238932
        p420.2500  p520.2500     p54.2500    p9.2500    u118.2500  u179.2500  u21.2500    u22.2500
   0.001456685 0.00108458 0.0003695966 0.02501649 0.0005977814 0.01711885 0.0558054 0.002357498
        u23.2500    u27.2500     u28.2500   u78.2500   Unit5.2500
   0.00040357 0.001422519 0.0002764237 0.01699094 4.835942e-05

    write.csv(predout, "Predout.csv", row.names=TRUE)
```

I can write the probability of occurrence values from predtable to a set of 36 new raster images via:

```
names <- names(predtable)
for (i in 1:length(names)) { 
  SpatialPointspredTable <- SpatialPointsDataFrame (coords=coords, data=predtable[i])
  gridded(SpatialPointspredTable)=TRUE
  rasValues <- raster(SpatialPointspredTable)
  projection(rasValues) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-16.237,3.51,9.939,1.4157e-006,2.1477e-006,1.3429e-006,1.91e-007 +no_defs"
  plot(rasValues)
  writeRaster(rasValues, filename=names[i], format="HFA", overwrite=TRUE)
}
```

this gives me the outputs I want - HOWEVER -the instead of having to predict out to a dataframe - the process would be a lot faster and more efficient if it were possible to predict directly to a rasterbrick.

If I run

```
predict(rasStack,
         gbmmodel,
         n.trees=best.iter,
         filename="multiclass_BRT_20p_test_idrisi",
         format="IDRISI",
         na.rm=FALSE,
         type="response",
         overwrite=TRUE,
         progress="text",
         cores=8)
```

The output is raster grid that represents the first vegetation community that I want to predict:

```
|=========================================================| 100%

class       : RasterLayer
dimensions  : 33, 37, 1221  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent      : 149.1268, 149.1371, -35.65473, -35.64556  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA
data source : /mnt/scratch/mcilwea/R/TSG/multiclass_BRT_20p_test_idrisi.rdc
names       : layer
values      : 3.762369e-06, 0.9337785  (min, max)
```

The IDRISI file format does not support multi-band images so I can't add index=1:36 into the mix to produce a multiband rasterbrick as the output. If I try to do this - setting format="GTiff" or "HFA" (or any other format that requires rgdal) I get the error message:
 
*"Error in rgdal::putRasterData(x@file@transient, v, band = 1, offset = off) : Failure during raster IO"*

I can however get a rasterbrick output if I set the format="raster", but this wont let me read/write any data other than that in the idrisi image (the first output column from the predict.gbm model)

*"Warning message:
In .rasterFromRasterFile(grdfile, band = band, objecttype, ...) :
  size of values file does not match the number of cells (given the data type)"*

```
predrast <- predict(object=rasStack,
        model=gbmmodel,
        n.trees=best.iter,
        filename="multi_test",
        fun=predict.gbm,
        format="raster",
        index=1:5,
        bandorder="BIL",
        ext=extent(rasStack[[1:20]]), 
        na.rm=FALSE,
        type="response",
        datatype="FLT4S",
        overwrite=TRUE,
        progress="text",
        cores=8) 
|=====================================================================100%

predrast

class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 33, 37, 1221, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
extent      : 149.1268, 149.1371, -35.65473, -35.64556  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-16.237,3.51,9.939,1.4157e-006,2.1477e-006,1.3429e-006,1.91e-007 +no_defs 
data source : C:\Data\FINAL_TSG\test\multi_test.grd 
names       :      layer.1,      layer.2,      layer.3,      layer.4,      layer.5 
min values  : 3.762369e-06, 3.762369e-06, 3.762369e-06, 3.762369e-06, 3.762369e-06 
max values  :    0.9337785,    0.9337785,    0.9337785,    0.9337785,    0.9337785
```

If I try to convert the rasterbrick above to a set of individual raster images

```
writeRaster(predrast, filename="multi_test.img", format="HFA", bylayer=TRUE, suffix="numbers", overwrite=TRUE)
```

none of the images make any sense.

It also a little puzzling, that if I try to write as a multiband CDF image I get a different set of warning messages to the rgdal error:

```
    |   0%
Error in ncdf::put.var.ncdf(nc, x@title, v, start = c(1, start, lstart),  : 
  put.var.ncdf: error: you asked to write 11988 values, but the passed data array only has 11840 entries!
  |========                                                       |  25%
Error in ncdf::put.var.ncdf(nc, x@title, v, start = c(1, start, lstart),  : 
  put.var.ncdf: error: you asked to write 11988 values, but the passed data array only has 11840 entries!
  |==================                                              |  50%
Error in ncdf::put.var.ncdf(nc, x@title, v, start = c(1, start, lstart),  : 
  put.var.ncdf: error: you asked to write 11988 values, but the passed data array only has 11840 entries!
  |===============================================                   |  75%
Error in ncdf::put.var.ncdf(nc, x@title, v, start = c(1, start, lstart),  : 
  put.var.ncdf: error: you asked to write 7992 values, but the passed data array only has 7955 entries!
  |=============================================================| 100%
```

Here, I am not sure what's going on??

It would be great if someone with the know how could work with the authors of the gbm package to make it possible predict directly out to a rasterbrick, without running into any of the problems above.

If anyone wants to know the code I have used on the full raster grid, leave a comment below and I am happy to supply.

cheers
Allen

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ncdf_1.6.8      rgdal_0.9-1     gbm_2.1         lattice_0.20-30 survival_2.37-7 raster_2.3-24   sp_1.0-17      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.1.2  tools_3.1.2

# Traceback error for
Error in rgdal::putRasterData(x@file@transient, v, band = 1, offset = off) : 
  Failure during raster IO

> traceback()
7: .Call("RGDAL_PutRasterData", raster, rasterData, as.integer(offset), 
       PACKAGE = "rgdal")
6: rgdal::putRasterData(x@file@transient, v, band = 1, offset = off)
5: writeValues(predrast, predv, tr$row[i])
4: writeValues(predrast, predv, tr$row[i])
3: .local(object, ...)
2: predict(object = rasStack, model = gbmmodel, n.trees = best.iter, 
       filename = "multi_img", format = "HFA", na.rm = FALSE, type = "response", 
       datatype = "FLT4S", overwrite = TRUE, progress = "text")
1: predict(object = rasStack, model = gbmmodel, n.trees = best.iter, 
       filename = "multi_img", format = "HFA", na.rm = FALSE, type = "response", 
       datatype = "FLT4S", overwrite = TRUE, progress = "text")
```